# Displaying custom-taxonomy-terms sorted by parent/child-hierarchy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy (to show some "best practice" examples on my website). On the single-post-page (single-bestpractice.php) I wanted to show all the terms (categories) like this:

**Parent:** Child, Child, Child

I tried this code:

```
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('bestpractice');
if (count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0) {
    foreach ($customPostTaxonomies as $tax) {
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'show_count' => 0,
            'pad_counts' => 0,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'title_li' => ''
        );  
        wp_list_categories( $args );
    }
}
```

which outputs:

Child, Child, Parent, Child,

…so, is there a way to sort it by parent/child and make the parent one start with a ":" and remove the "," of the last child?

thanx,
Jochen

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97957/display-parent-taxonomy-name-and-list-child-taxonomies-below-it

Answer (score 0):

You might like to follow this post as well as it appears to be essentially the same...
[Display the Terms from a Custom Taxonomy Assigned to a Post(inside the loop) in Hierarchial Order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114443/display-the-terms-from-a-custom-taxonomy-assigned-to-a-postinside-the-loop-in)