# Display the Terms from a Custom Taxonomy Assigned to a Post(inside the loop) in Hierarchial Order

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

[This link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Categories_Assigned_to_a_Post) tells me how to display categories assigned to a post.

How would I modify this code to display the terms from a custom taxonomy assigned to a post in hierarchical order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of what you are trying to do exactly. But if you want the same functionality of the question you linked, you can use the same function but passing your custom taxonomy to the function. Here all the arguments you can pass to `wp_list_categories()` and is defulat values:

```
<?php $args = array(
     'show_option_all'    => '',
         //Possible values of orderby: ID, name, slug, count, term_group 
     'orderby'            => 'name',
     'order'              => 'ASC',
     'style'              => 'list',
     'show_count'         => 0,
     'hide_empty'         => 1,
     'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
     'child_of'           => 0,
     'feed'               => '',
     'feed_type'          => '',
     'feed_image'         => '',
     'exclude'            => '',
     'exclude_tree'       => '',
     'include'            => '',
     'hierarchical'       => 1,
     'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
     'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
     'number'             => null,
     'echo'               => 1,
     'depth'              => 0,
     'current_category'   => 0,
     'pad_counts'         => 0,
          //Change this with your custom taxonomy
     'taxonomy'           => 'your_custom_taxonomy',
      'walker'             => null
);
wp_list_categories($args);
?>
```

The above code will generate a list in hierarchical order with all the terms from the specified taxonomy, not only the associated to the current post. But we can limit the included terms using the `inlcude` argument:

```
<?php
global $post;
$taxonomy = 'your_taxonomy';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $args = array(
                'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
                'include'     => $term_ids,
                //Add more arguments if you need them with a different value from default
            );
    $terms = wp_list_categories($args);

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
?>
```

Comment: I've already tried that with no luck

Comment: In my suggested code, have you changed `'your_custom_taxonomy'` by the slug of your custom taxonomy?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/displayshowlist-custom-terms-in-heirarchy-order-not-alphanumerical

Comment: Please, add code or new information directly into your question.

Comment: Can you try the new suggestion I've made in my answer?

Comment: I tried it but still no joy

Comment: You have to be making something wrong. It is working perfectly here and the code has been taking directly from [Wordpress official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Categories_Assigned_to_a_Post). Note that if the post only has assigned a child term, the parents won't be shown as the list has been limited to "terms associated to the post".